# How to execute a code after an animation?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

I have this simple code:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BGEditTextField * theTableViewCell = (BGEditTextField *) [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    theTableViewCell.displaytextField =true;
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    //self.helpFinishUpdating.viewNotToCover = theTableViewCell;
}
```

Everything is perfect except that I want

`self.helpFinishUpdating.viewNotToCover = theTableViewCell`

to be executed after
`[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];` is done.

How would I achieve that?

The reason why I want to do so is because `self.helpFinishUpdating.viewNotToCover = theTableViewCell;` is sensitive toward the frame location of the `UITableViewCell`. I want the `UITableViewCell` to reach the final position first before executing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITableViewDelegate` conforms to `UIScrollViewDelegate`, so you can just implement `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` or whatever fits your needs.

Comment: good enough. but then, what about if users initiate the scrolling? I can work things out, but not that simple.

Comment: I take that as a compliment :D